# Cannot use JSONP with specific url

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Why i can't use JSONP Store with this url http://www.sozler.im/rest/categories 
When i am trying on Sencha Architect, right click on Store/Load Data it gives an error, but it works on browser
Here is the source

```
Ext.define('SozlerimMobile.store.CategoryStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'SozlerimMobile.model.Categories',
    'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
    'Ext.data.reader.Json'
],

config: {
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    model: 'SozlerimMobile.model.Categories',
    storeId: 'CategoryStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        extraParams: {
            Status: 'Active'
        },
        url: 'http://www.sozler.im/rest/categories/',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            clientIdProperty: 'id',
            idProperty: 'id',
            rootProperty: ''
        }
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webservice has to return JSONP (JSON with function callback - see http://json-p.org/)

The more info can be found in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067584/282834

Comment: Martin, You think this service does not have a callback function?

Comment: Just check the Chrome Dev Tools, to see the request. There would be something like `?callback=JSONPCallback1` or something similar. And the response should be wrapped in `JSONPCallback1(...)`